# MySQL updating records with condition

Tags: php, mysql

Table A

```
id | name | important |
-----------------------
 1   Abe        0
 2   Ann        1
 3   John       1
 4   Bill       0
```

I have a php array of id values

```
 $ids = [1, 4];
```

I want update table A  setting important column equals 1
if id column value is in $ids array AND setting important column value
equals 0 if not.

So for the example, the table after update would be:

```
id | name | important |
-----------------------
 1   Abe        1
 2   Ann        0
 3   John       0
 4   Bill       1
```

How to do?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Are you looking to achieve this in a single query specifically or it doesn't matter? Have you made any attempts to write the query/queries? It's `update... where...`, nothing more.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Basically you need to run next query:

```
UPDATE TableA SET important = (id IN (1,4));
```

Below php implementation of this:

```
<?php
$ids = [1,4];

//prepare SQL statement with plaseholders
$placeholder =  implode(',', array_pad([], count($ids) , '?'));
$sql = "UPDATE TableA SET important = (id IN ($placeholder));";

// run update with ids
$pdo->prepare($sql)->execute($ids);

// Get updated data for check result
$sth = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM TableA");
$sth->execute();

print_r($sth->fetchAll());
```

And [here](https://phpize.online/?phpses=ff01aa252f673b5b8e61c01297b26488&sqlses=203eae499009468bae46cf8a7be7beb0&php_version=php7&sql_version=mysql80) you can test the code.

Answer (score -1):

**First make array safe before insert**

```
$ids = array_map('intval', $ids);
```

**Then insert with one query**

```
<?php


"UPDATE TableA SET important=1 WHERE id in(" . implode(',',$ids) . ");"
```

Comment: The `mysql_` extension has been deprecated and removed from PHP as of v7.

Comment: @el-vanja also i dont use `mysql_` in my answer, i write a string only !

Comment: See about sql injection and the importance of prepared and bound queries

Comment: Yes, it is important. It's been deprecated since 5.5 (that was in 2013). Recommending to use functionalities that have been deprecated for over 7 years is irresponsible.

Comment: @strawberry Can any body bypass `intval` to do sql injection!? i think you dont know what "sql injection" is, and what "intval" is, You dont read even first line of the answer :)

Comment: Still running PHP4 today is also irresponsible, from the security perspective.

Comment: @a55 provided safe and elegant solution.

Comment: Thank you a55. Your solution for that matter is good enougth to me!

Answer (score -1):

i am update id value using `php pdo`. and its work successfully.

first i can try given id value update in 1. and then after try to all ids value update in 0.

so please try this code.

```
<?php

//This is a database connection

$host_name = 'localhost';
$db_name = 'stackoverflow';
$user_name = 'root';
$password = '';

$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$host_name; dbname=$db_name;", $user_name, $password);
 
$ids = [1, 4]; //This is a id for update value is 1

$sqlforOneVal = "UPDATE important SET important = 1 WHERE id in (".(implode(', ', $ids)).")";
$updateforOne = $conn->prepare($sqlforOneVal);
$updateforOne->execute();

$sqlforZeroVal = "UPDATE important SET important = 0 WHERE id not in (".(implode(', ', $ids)).")";
$updateforZero = $conn->prepare($sqlforZeroVal);
$updateforZero->execute();

?>
```